# Ты придёшь скоро — и я тогда буду рад(,) — или ты придёшь не скоро?

Tags: запятые

Нужна запятая? Я думаю, нет, т. к. оба части предложения — вопросительные.

> Ты придёшь скоро — и я тогда буду рад(,) — или ты придёшь не скоро?

Comment: А, извиняюсь, если обосабливаем тире, запятая уже не нужна из-за вопросительной интонации. Я прочитал тсточники другие.

Comment: Почему повторяется вопрос? Множество вопросов сегодняшнего дня – это откровенный СПАМ.  Написаны второпях, небрежно, темы неясные или простейшие.  В общем, качество Лео-вопросов  НИКАКОЕ.  Разговорный характер надоел, а Максим вас копирует. Вы так не думаете?

Answer (score 2):

*Ты придёшь скоро — **и я тогда буду рад,**  — или ты придёшь не скоро?*

Вставка, два тире, запятая перенесенная. Вставка относится к первой части предложения.

Это сложное предложение (ССП). Вопросительная интонация **не может быть общей** в предложении, где есть вставная конструкция, поэтому запятая перед И ставится по обычным правилам.

Вставная конструкция выделяется **двумя паузами**, общий пониженный **тон**.

**[ВСТАВОЧНАЯ ИНТОНАЦИЯ](https://studopedia.ru/13_26981_g-sintaksicheskoe-vklyuchenie.html)**

**Интонация вводности** характеризуется ускоренным, беглым **темпом,** слабой ударностью, «приглушённый», более **низкий регистр** произнесения по сравнению с остальной частью предложения. Такая интонация создаёт впечатление чего-то **второстепенного, добавочного**: Он, видимо, устал.

Comment: Но если вставку убрать, то получится без запятой! *Ты придёшь скоро или ты придёшь не скоро?*

Comment: А что восклицать-то?  Это там, а у нас  здесь. Я вот что думаю: не сместить ли мне запятую влево? Ведь  вставка относится к первой части. How do you like the idea?  It's like my new theory.

Comment: It would be complete nonsense. The comma is yet to be justified.

Comment: Да неужели? Я ее не переношу, а оставляю на месте. Вы понимаете, что равновесия нет?  А как это обозначить?

Comment: I still don't understand why there's got to be a comma despite both parts of the sentence being questions.

Comment: Вопрос. интонация – это не вопрос, а повышение голоса в конце фразы. У нас не общего повышения, а есть отдельное для каждой части. Знаки ставятся в соответствии с реальной интонацией заданного предложения, а не исходного.

Comment: Да, первая часть не произносится вопросительно, но подразумевается вопрос же. Не спорю — говорю своë мнение.

Comment: У Розенталя говорится об интонации. Интонация не может подразумеваться. Вы слышите предложение? Вставка симметричная или смещенная?  Все это нужно изобразить графически.

Comment: Пусть так, но почему запятая перед вставкой, а не после? Вставка относится к ПЕРВОЙ части — следовательно, не отделяется от нее запятой и отделяется от последующей. А про интонацию где говорится у него? Есть ссылочка?

Comment: Максиму ссылочки нужны)  Одна ссылочка – одна печенька, ОК?  Недорого! Начнем с Розенталя:  2) перед ПЕРВЫМ тире ставится запятая, если этого требует структура ПЕРВОЙ части основного предложения: Он посмотрел на пепелище, которое окружало его, — какой ужас! — и руки бессильно опустились у него — запятая закрывает придаточную часть сложноподчиненного предложения.   Ваш ход?

Comment: Sharon, мне нравился ваш первый вариант, с запятой перед вторым тире. А сейчас действительно вставка совсем оторвана от первой части.

Comment: Ладно, пусть будет так. Если нет запятой,  то вставка смещена влево.

Answer (score 1):

> Ты придёшь скоро — и я тогда буду рад(,) — или ты придёшь не скоро?
>
> Нужна запятая?

Нужна **точка**:

***Ты придёшь скоро — и я тогда буду рад. Или ты придёшь не скоро?***

Если же с вопросительной интонацией произносится и начальная часть (***Ты придёшь скоро?..***), то возможно и такое пунктуационное оформление:

***Ты придёшь скоро (и я тогда буду рад) или ты придёшь не скоро?***

Comment: Первое предложение тоже вопрос.

Comment: Ну, если обе части первого предложения объединены вопросительной интонацией, тогда и тире между ними не нужно: _**Ты придёшь скоро и я тогда буду рад? Или ты придёшь не скоро?**_

Comment: Или же, если часть «я тогда буду рад» не требует вопросительной интонации, можно использовать такое пунктуационное оформление: _**Ты придёшь скоро (и я тогда буду рад) или ты придёшь не скоро?**_